# Height of absolute-positioned div is ignored

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this simple html structure:

```
<div id="mainbody">
  <div id="main">
  ...
  </div>
  <div id="left">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
...
</div>
```

The div "mainbody" has position:relative.
The div "left" has absolute position at the left side of the page and dynamic height.
The div "main" floats left at the right of div "left".

CSS:

```
#mainbody {
    position:relative;
}
#left {
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
}
#main {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 260px;
    width:80%;
}
```

PROBLEM: The height of div "left" is ignored and the div "footer" starts where the div "main" ends even though the div "left" has bigger height than div "main".

Comment: must see CSS as well to accurately answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) so that your elements will load properly. See [the linked SO question "Which method of 'clearfix' is best?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) for numerous possible clearfixes.

The reason why the `footer` element places itself next to the `main` element is because absolutely-positioned elements are removed from the page flow. As a result, later elements treat the absolutely-positioned element as if it was not there in the first place. With a clearfix, this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a clear after floated elements if you do not want following elements to be affected.

This can be achieved two ways:

1. Add css clear:both or clear:right to a following element.  (such as a  after div#left.  Or to #footer.
2. Add overflow:auto to div#mainbody

BTW if you want more specific or accurate answers, I suggest you include both your html and css.